# Hider URL parameter on Symfony2 using a click on a button

Tags: symfony, twig

There is a button with the following `href` in Twig:

```
<a href="{{ path('pathhere', {'value': values.id}) }}">
<button type="submit" id="bookApp" name="bookApp" style="margin-left:15px;width: 300px">Click me</button>
</a>
```

When I click on the button, it directs me to another Twig file. I need the value of the `value` to access it from another controller. But the problem is that the `value` is on the URL address. Is there any way I could hide it but still be able to access on the controller?

Comment: Why not use  $.ajax?

Comment: Hello sir, I am not required to use $.ajax

Comment: You have 2 options, pass it in the URL or query string, or instead of a link, construct a form which submits this parameter in the request body. The latter will hide the parameter from the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir @Gerry - the 2nd option is the one i have implemented.

Comment: In my opinion wrapping `<button>` inside `<a>` is highly irregular...

Comment: Change your form `method` to "post":  `<form method="post" action=... >`.